# Optimising a calculation on every cumulative subset of a vector in R

Tags: r, loops, optimization, vectorization

I have a collection of DNA sequencing reads of various lengths, sorted from longest to shortest. I would like to know the largest number of reads I can include in a set such that the N50 of that set is above some threshold `t`

For any given set of reads, the total amount of data is just the cumulative sum of the lengths of the reads. The `N50` is defined as the length of the read such that half of the data are contained in reads at least that long.

I have a solution below, but it is slow for very large read sets. I tried vectorising it, but this was slower (probably because my threshold is usually relatively large, such that my solution below stops calculating fairly early on).

Here's a worked example:

```
df = data.frame(l = 100:1) # read lengths
df$cs = cumsum(df$l) # getting the cumulative sum is easy and quick

t = 95 # let's imagine that this is my threshold N50

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    N50 = df$l[min(which(df$cs>df$cs[i]/2))]
    if(N50 < t){ break }
}

# the loop will have gone one too far, so I subtract one
number.of.reads = as.integer(i-1)
```

This works fine on small datasets, but my actual data are more like 5m reads that vary from ~200,000 to 1 in length (longer reads are rarer), and I'm interested in an N50 of 100,000, then it gets pretty slow.

This example is closer to something that's realistic. It takes ~15s on my desktop.

```
l = ceiling(runif(100000, min = 0, max = 19999))
l = sort(l, decreasing = T)

df = data.frame(l = l)
df$cs = cumsum(df$l)

t = 18000

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    n = df$l[min(which(df$cs>df$cs[i]/2))]
    if(n < t){ break }
}

result = as.integer(i-1)
```

So, I'm interested in any ideas, tips, or tricks to noticeably optimise this. It seems like this should be possible, but I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `n` is decreasing with `i`, you should use a [binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

```
binSearch <- function(min, max) {
  print(mid <- floor(mean(c(min, max))))
  if (mid == min) {
    if (df$l[min(which(df$cs>df$cs[min]/2))] < t) {
      return(min - 1)
    } else {
      return(max - 1)
    }
  }

  n = df$l[min(which(df$cs>df$cs[mid]/2))]
  if (n >= t) {
    return(binSearch(mid, max))
  } else {
    return(binSearch(min, mid))
  }
}
```

Then, just call

```
binSearch(1, nrow(df))
```

Comment: Ah, thanks so much. The funny thing is I had a vague memory of learning something like this a long time ago. But I couldn't remember the name, and certainly couldn't have coded up such a succinct version of it.

Comment: Can confirm that I have implemented this, that it gives exactly the same answers as my code above, and that it is drastically faster (as expected).

Answer (score 0):

Since your data are ordered by DNA/read length, maybe you could avoid testing every single row. On the contrary, you can iterate and test a limited number of rows (reasonably spaced) at each iteration (using `while()` for example), and so get progressively closer to your solution. This should make things much faster. Just make sure that once you get close to the solution, you stop iterating.

This is your solution

```
set.seed(111)
l = ceiling(runif(100000, min = 0, max = 19999))
l = sort(l, decreasing = T)

df = data.frame(l = l)
df$cs = cumsum(df$l)

t = 18000

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  n = df$l[min(which(df$cs>df$cs[i]/2))]
  if(n < t){ break }
}

result = as.integer(i-1)
result 
# 21216, in ~29 seconds
```

Instead of testing every row, let's set a range

```
i1 <- 1
i2 <- nrow(df)
i.range <- as.integer(seq(i1, i2, length.out = 10))
```

Now, test only these 10 rows. Get the closest one and "focus in" by re-defining the range. Stop when you cannot increase granularity.

```
while(sum(duplicated(i.range))==0){
  for(i in 1:length(i.range)){
    N50 = df$l[min(which(df$cs>df$cs[i.range[i]]/2))]
    if(N50 < t){ break }
  }

  #update i1 and i2
  i1 <- i.range[(i-1)]
  i2 <- i.range[i]
  i.range <- as.integer(seq(i1, i2, length.out = 10))

}

i.range <- seq(i1, i2, by=1)
for(i in i.range){
  N50 = df$l[min(which(df$cs>df$cs[i]/2))]
  if(N50 < t){ break }
}
result <- as.integer(i-1)
result 
#21216, in ~ 0.06 seconds

Same result in a fraction of the time.
```

Comment: I don't have a proof, but this looks a lot like it would be asymptotically as fast as binary search as you reduce the number of rows you test to 1.